# What should be my Database Design for user's data.

Tags: mysql

I want to add a login/register option to my website.

So, for this, I want to store: `Username`, `Password`,`email`,`first name` `middle name` `last name` and user's `watchlist` of movies, and there `rating`

This is the design, which  i am planning to make (Not sure, if you call this as `normalization`, or it is something else)

Table: `userinfo`

```
user_id    username    password   email               first name 

 1          fsdfs       4r34fdf    dsf@gmail.com         josh
 2          dfdsf       e4rewff     fds@gmai.co          roy
```

Table: userwatchlist:

```
user_id     watchlist
1           Logan
1           Ironman 
1           Ironman 2
1           Ironman 3
2           Superman 
2           The boy
```

Table: user_rating

```
   user_id     rating       movie_id
    1           5.6             435
    1           6.9             3423
    1           5.8             3243
    1           9.4             2334
    2           7.8             6345
    2           8.3             4343
```

I will connect all tables using `user_id` as foreign key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't store passwords. Store their salted hashes.
A better design would be

```
users table
-----------
id
username
pass_hash
...


movies table
------------
id
title
...


watchlist table
---------------
user_id
movie_id
```

user_ratings table is fine

Comment: Bro, in watchlist, If i put `movie_name` instead of `movie_id`, it will slow down the execution speed? (while fetching data)???

Comment: I am not your bro. Besides that why would you store redundant data in the watchist table? It would be cleaner to store only the ID. And what if you misspelled a movie title? You would have to correct that in more than one table.

Comment: I am sorry. Actually sir, I have another table, in which, I stored results with Movie_name instead of movie_id. and the table is done. Should i change my table structure to what you advised? Or keep it like that? I want to improve my fetching Speed, will it effect speed?

Comment: It probably will not effect speed. When designing a DB it is not all about speed. Watch out to keep your design also clean and normalized. I would advice to store the movie name only in one place.